# Fish shell functions show $argv in job control, not file

Tags: fish

I'm trying to switch to fish shell but I've run into one sticking point. If I alias vi to vim and edit a file, I can't see which file I'm editing in job control.

```
polis@josh1 ~> function testvi
                   vim $argv
               end
polis@josh1 ~> functions testvi
function testvi
    vim $argv
end
polis@josh1 ~> testvi foobar
polis@josh1 ~> jobs
Job Group   CPU State   Command
2   26087   0%  stopped vim $argv
```

How do I make it so the output is:

```
2   26087   0%  stopped vim foobar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where a command abbreviation is preferable to an alias (i.e., a function):

```
abbr -a vi vim
```

Now when you type "vi" and press space it will be magically replaced by "vim". You can do more complicated expansions. For example I use these abbreviations quite a bit:

```
abbr -a gca git commit --amend
abbr -a gcm git checkout master
```

The advantages of the abbreviation is they are much simpler than a function and the expansion shows up in your shell history which I find more useful than an aliased function name.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is we want to expand `$argv` first into a new command, and then execute that. We can do that with `eval`.

However, this has the wrinkle that any special characters in the new command will be interpreted, so we need to escape them first.

The overall function is:

```
function testvi
    eval "vim "(string escape $argv)
end
```

This uses the new `string` builtin, which is in the just-released fish 2.3.0.

Illustration of the result, here editing a file 'foobar $baz' to show that escaping works:

```
> testvi 'foobar $baz'
> jobs
Job Group   State   Command
 5  60249   stopped vim 'foobar $baz'
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the job title to be set before expanding the variables?